Upgrading Wix from v4 to v5: Ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui' namespace has been provided
In Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, I attempted to upgrade my Wix install set by updating the Nuget package dependencies (WixToolset.netfx.wixext and WixToolset.UI.wixext) for the Wix installer from version 4 to version 5.0.2
The error I get is in my one .wxs file:
<ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

The error:
Error (active)  WIX0200 The UI element contains an unhandled extension element 'WixUI'. Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui' namespace has been provided.
At the top of the same file, there is
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui" >

(unchanged, before, in v4 it was building correctly)

The problem is most likely in your .wixproj and/or not rebuilding fully. Can you add it?

In the .wixproj, I had the line:
<Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="4.0.2" />

which I had to change to
<Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk" Version="5.0.2" />

